# Silverstripe :: Custom templates

Tags: templates, silverstripe

I am in the process of re-factoring my site. I have lots of page types (i.e pagetype.php) and each page type has its own template .ss file. All working fine. Looking at them closely, most of the templates have same layout (i.e 2 column or 3 column). so I decided to generalize the template so that I can reduce the clutter, eazy to maintain also.

Silverstripe by default looks for .ss, is there a way I can make pagetype1.php, pagetype2.php, pagetype3.php, all to use twocolumn.ss template

R

Comment: You can use something like `$this->renderWith("TwoColumn");` in your `index()` function in your page controller. I'll try to flesh out a detailed answer later when I have some time, if someone else doesn't get to it first. Hopefully this helps you in the right direction for now.

Comment: thanks, have done this :-)

Answer (score 1):

We can use [`renderWith()`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-ViewableData.html#312-340) in our `index()` function in our page controller to control what template a page type should use.

Here is some example code:

```
class PageType_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    function index() {
        return $this->renderWith(
            array('TwoColumn', 'Page')
        );
    }
}
```

In this example we tell the controller to render the page with `array('TwoColumn', 'Page')`. What seems to happen with this is the `Page.ss` is used for the main template. Then `TwoColumn.ss` is used for the Layout template.

One thing to keep in mind with this code is if we have any other actions on the controller that may be used on the front end we need to also call `renderWith` in each one of these actions. Otherwise the default template for the page will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Either you define (as 3dgoo stated) `$this->renderWith("TwoColumn");`, or - if you don't want to solve this in code but in templates alone - you can split out the twocolumns layout into an own file in *Includes* dir, let's say */templates/Includes/TwoColumn.ss*.

Then e.g. in */templates/Layout/PageType1.ss* do

```
<% include TwoColumn %>
```

This way you can define the layout easily in your templates or theme.